# NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) work only first time swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

.navigationBarItems(trailing:
      NavigationLink(destination: SomeView()) { Text("some") }
)

go on SomeView() but when i go back i can't go second time on this view.

Comment: This is a pretty known issue on the simulator. Does it work correctly on device?

Comment: It's working on device

Comment: yes, work on device